# Paypal IPN Verification 404

Tags: paypal-ipn

I posted this in the Paypal community and have heard NADA. I've had Paypal IPN listener set up for years on my site, and until 1/11/23, everything was working fine.

Then on 1/11, I started to see 404 errors when trying to verify an IPN message from paypal. I'm *receiving* the IPN from paypal, but it's the return verification which is failing with the 404.

The procedure according to their docs is to post back your message prefixed with a "cmd=_notify-validate". I've had this running forever just fine. This procedure is outlined in their developer docs located here:
https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/ipn/IPNIntro/

Now when my system tries to verify the message, Paypal responds with a 404 for the following URL:

https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

I'm also getting a 404 for the sandbox url.

I've searched to see if I missed some changes which were going to be introduced (url change?) but can't find anything anywhere.

Besides a URL change, is there something else I might be missing?

Comment: Interesting. I was posting cmd=_notify-validate back to webscr rather than having it in the URL, and it has worked all this time. Thank you!

Comment: You need to do a POST request but the parameters in the URL must be transfered the same way they came in (via GET): `Your listener HTTPS POSTs the complete, unaltered message back to PayPal.`